# Printing computer name using GetComputerNameW

Tags: c, winapi

I am new to Windows APIs. I am doing an exercise on printing the computer name to the console. Here is the code I have so far:

```
wchar_t compName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH+1];
DWORD maxSize = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH+1 ;
BOOL getName = GetComputerNameW(compName, &maxSize);

wprintf(L"Computer name is: %s",compName);
```

The issue is on the output. I only see `Computer name is D` on the console, when I should see `DESKTOP-XXXXXX`.

What am I doing wrong? I believe I am calling the right functions, per the MSDN docs. I have seen posts on StackOverflow regarding this issue, but it is in C++ and not C.

I feel like it has something to do with me printing a Unicode string.

Comment: "*I have seen posts on StackOverflow regarding this issue, but it is in C++ and not C*" - the Windows API works exactly the same way in C and C++

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The format specifier `%s` is for printing a string pointed at by `char*`, even in `wprintf`.

You should use format specifier `%ls` to print a string of wide characters.

[printf, _printf_l, wprintf, _wprintf_l | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/printf-printf-l-wprintf-wprintf-l?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Thanks so much for showing me, I can't believe I have been stuck on this for 3 hours! Looking at the documentation I guess I could also do %S also? It seemed to work

Comment: "*The format specifier `%s` is for printing a string pointed at by `char*`, even in `wprintf`.*" - that is wrong. `printf()` interprets `%s` as `char*`, and `wprintf()` interprets `%s` as `wchar_t*`. This is [documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=msvc-170#type): "*Character and string arguments that are specified by using `c` and `s` are interpreted as `char` and `char*` by `printf` family functions, **or as `wchar_t` and `wchar_t*` by `wprintf` family functions**.*"

Comment: The *standard* `wprintf()` does indeed interpret `%s` as `char*` and `%ls` as `wchar_t*`, but that is [not how Microsoft's `wprintf()` behaves](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=msvc-170#type): "***This behavior is Microsoft-specific.** For historical reasons, **the `wprintf` functions use `c` and `s` to refer to `wchar_t` characters**, and `C` and `S` specify narrow characters.*"

Comment: "*The `Z` type character, and the behavior of the `c`, `C`, `s`, and `S` type characters when they're used with the `printf` and `wprintf` functions, **are Microsoft extensions**. The ISO C standard uses `c` and `s` consistently for narrow characters and strings, and `C` and `S` for wide characters and strings, in all formatting functions.*" Fortunately, Microsoft's `wprintf()` does support `%ls` to mean `wchar_t*`, so your solution will work.  But your opening statement is wrong, when using `wprintf()` in a Microsoft compiler (the OP did not state which compiler they are actually using).

Comment: As Remy says, this answer is incorrect. See [Format specification syntax: printf and wprintf functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=msvc-170)

Comment: @JonathanPotter only the 1st sentence is wrong, when using Microsoft's flavor of `wprintf()` rather than a standard `wprintf()`. The solution (using `%ls`) is fine, though.

Comment: @RemyLebeau When the answer consists of only two sentences plus a link, one of the sentences being wrong is significant.